# How to sort a list of classes by defined field in alphanumeric based on numbers in Groovy?

Tags: sorting, groovy, alphanumeric

I need to check the specific sorting. There is list of classes:

```
[
no = '1'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_2',

no = '2'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_11',

no = '3'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_10',

no = '4'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1',

no = '5'
field = '06633-146944-0000036012',

no = '6'
field = '06633-155867-0000051910',

no = '7'
field = '06687-250844-00002544203'
]
```

I have to sort by field in alphanumeric based on numbers and get the result like:

```
[
no = '5'
field = '06633-146944-0000036012',

no = '6'
field = '06633-155867-0000051910',

no = '7'
field = '06687-250844-00002544203',

no = '4'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1',

no = '1'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_2',

no = '3'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_10',

no = '2'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_11'
]
```

I tried:
result.sort{ a,b -> (((a.field =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer)  <=> ((b.field =~ /\d+/)[-1] as Integer))
}

but result was:

```
[
no = '4'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1',

no = '1'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_2',

no = '3'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_10',

no = '2'
field = 'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_11',

no = '5'
field = '06633-146944-0000036012',

no = '6'
field = '06633-155867-0000051910',

no = '7'
field = '06687-250844-00002544203'
]
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Why do you expect `1` in `FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1` to come after `2544203` in `06687-250844-00002544203`?

Comment: yet another question with "sorting like in Excel" magic...

Comment: tim_yates: I should check sorting in UI which exposed by typescript. I need to write a test for checking this sorting.

Comment: This solution works well for List of string https://dirask.com/posts/Java-how-to-sort-alphanumeric-array-of-Strings-natural-order-sorting-VDKErj  But I can't implement this decision for list of classes

Comment: But the order you show as desired makes no logical sense. Unless you can tell us the secret rules for sorting, we cannot help

Comment: First shohld be fields with digits based on numbers, then alphanumeric based on numbers its the logic, how I see...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one-liner:

```
def data = [
  'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_2',
  '06687-250844-00002544204',
  '06687-250844-00002544203',
  '06687-250844-00002544202',
  'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1',
  '06633-146944-0000036012',
  '06633-155867-0000051910',
  'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_11',
  'FEE_HIG_R_test1234_10',
]

def result = data.sort{ 
   it ==~ /\d+-\d+-\d+/ 
      ? it.replaceAll( '-', '' ).toBigDecimal() 
      : 10000000000000000000000 + ( it =~ /\d+/ )[ -1 ].toInteger() 
}

assert result.join( '\n' ) == '''\
06633-146944-0000036012
06633-155867-0000051910
06687-250844-00002544202
06687-250844-00002544203
06687-250844-00002544204
FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1
FEE_HIG_R_test1234_2
FEE_HIG_R_test1234_10
FEE_HIG_R_test1234_11'''
```

The `1000000... +`  is needed to push the smaller numbers in strings like `FEE_HIG_R_test1234_1` further to the right.

Comment: Thank you. I don;t have any issues with sorting List<String>. But data is not a simple List. Its a List of classes. Class has two(for example) fields - String 'no' and String' field' I need to sort this list by some field of this class. In this case I have to sort by field 'field' in required order.

Comment: you have to provide a reproducible and compilable example. Nobody has time to re-build your setup for you